# Can a probability density function be used directly as probability function?

Tags: probability-distributions

This might be something basic but it confuses me greatly.

I am reading a literature, where they use the probability density function of a Gaussian distribution, that is

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

directly as a probability function - that means,

$$p(x\mid\sigma^2,\mu)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }\;.$$

However, from what I read elsewhere, probability density function cannot be used like that, because it can be bigger than 1.

So I am confused.

Comment: It looks as if  that is just their notation for the density function.

Comment: oh. so it's not actual probability, it just... looks like probability?

Comment: I think $p$ is not a good name for a density function, the default if $f$ possibly with subscript, but I have seen $p$ before.

Comment: hm. no, further down, they specifically say that it's the probability (given those parameters).

Comment: Well, then it is wrong. Maybe they mean that $p(x)\,dx$ is a probability.

Comment: OK, no, I am wrong, I read this wrong. It really is a density function, just named $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the writer is making a mistake, the symbol $p$ is being used where it is more common to use $f$, possibly with subscript, as in $f_X$.

Some people use $p$, in the discrete case, for the probability mass function, and, in the continuous case, for the probability density function. In the continuous case, $p(x)$ is not a probability.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a [likelihood function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function). So $L(\theta|x) = P(x| \theta)$ instead of $P(\theta|x)$. The integral of the likelihood function over its domain could be greater than $1$.

Comment: OK. Now I am confused even more. :(